# Session not holding value - Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I set value to a session in my controller for my ussd application. In the controller, i set the values to sessions like below . When i check for value of  `Log::info(config('session.passcode'));` during `case 1`, the value is set to `pass i.e 234` which is accurate. But when the application gets to `case 2`, `Log::info(config('session.passcode'))` would know be showing the default value in `session.php` file.

Why am i not able to hold the value (234) into case 2?

```
   case '1':       
                   $phone = trim($explode[3]);
                   $code = '234'
                   $data = [
                            'passcode' => $pass
                           ];
                  Config::set('session', $data);                                        
                  Log::info(config('session.passcode')); 




 case '2':          
                  Log::info('Here);
                  Log::info(config('session.passcode'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set a session in laravel like:

```
case '1':       
   $phone = trim($explode[3]);
   $code = '234'
   $data = [
      'passcode' => $pass
   ];

   Session::put('data', $data);
   Log::info(Session::get('data'));
```

And get session variable like

```
case '2':
  Session::get('data');
  Log::info(Session::get('data'));
```

Comment: Even with Session, i keep losing the value. That is what i tried first. With Laravel 5.6, it is    `Session::put('data', $data);` not    `Session::set('data', $data);`

Comment: @stackauthstackauth It will not be saved when quitting the application(e.g. `dd()` in application development) in the midway or an exception is occurred.

So remove `dd()` if added.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
case '1':       
$phone = trim($explode[3]);
$code = '234'
$data = [
  'passcode' => $pass
];

Session::put('data', $data);
Session::save();
Log::info(Session::get('data'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the `session.php` configuration file [`Config::set('session',...)`] and the actual session.  The configuration file is just for storing settings, and is not actually writable through inline changes.

See the documentation for proper usage:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session#using-the-session

The easiest method is probably the global session helper, `session()`.

```php
// Retrieve a piece of data from the session...
$value = session('key');

// Specifying a default value...
$value = session('key', 'default');

// Store a piece of data in the session...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

Please note that the session is only written when a response is returned.  If you end a script prematurely, the session changes will not save unless done so explicitly.

```php
// force the session changes to be saved
session()->save();
```